# Flutter How to Populate ListView on app launch with sqflite?

Tags: flutter, listview, launch, sqflite

I'm trying to display data in a ListView with a FutureBuilder. In debug mode, when I launch the app, no data is displayed, but, if I reload the app (hot Reload or hot Restart), the ListView displays all the data. I already tried several approaches to solve this - even without a FutureBuilder, I still haven't succeeded. If I create a button to populate the ListView, with the same method "_getregistos()", the ListView returns the data correctly.
This is the code I'm using:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:xxxxx/models/task_model.dart';
import 'package:xxxxx/shared/loading.dart';

class AddTask extends StatefulWidget {
  static const id = 'add_task';

  @override
  _AddTaskState createState() => _AddTaskState();
}

class _AddTaskState extends State<AddTask> {
  dynamic tasks;
  final textController = TextEditingController();

  _getRegistos() async {
    List<TaskModel> taskList = await _todoHelper.getAllTask();
//    print('DADOS DA tasklist: ${taskList.length}');
    return taskList;
  }

  TaskModel currentTask;

  final TodoHelper _todoHelper = TodoHelper();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(32),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            TextField(
              controller: textController,
            ),
            FlatButton(
              child: Text('Insert'),
              onPressed: () {
                currentTask = TaskModel(name: textController.text);
                _todoHelper.insertTask(currentTask);
              },
              color: Colors.blue,
              textColor: Colors.white,
            ),
//
            FutureBuilder(
                future: _getRegistos(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    tasks = snapshot.data;
                    return ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: tasks == null ? 0 : tasks.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        TaskModel t = tasks[index];
                        return Card(
                          child: Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Text('id: ${t.id}'),
                              Text('name:  ${t.name}'),
                              IconButton(
                                  icon: Icon(Icons.delete), onPressed: () {})
                            ],
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    );
                  }

                  return Loading();
                }),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ConnectionState inside your builder. Look at this code template: (Currently your builder returns ListView widget without waiting for the future to complete)

```
return FutureBuilder(
future: yourFuture(),
builder: (context, snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
    // future complete
    // if error or data is false return error widget
    if (snapshot.hasError || !snapshot.hasData) {
      return _buildErrorWidget();
    }

    // return data widget
    return _buildDataWidget();

    // return loading widget while connection state is active
  } else
    return _buildLoadingWidget();
},
```

);

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help.
I already implemented ConnectionState in the FutureBuilder and the issue persists.
When I launch the app, I get error "ERROR  or No-Data" (is the message I defined in case of error of no-data.
If I click on the FlatButton to call the method "_getTasks()", the same method used in FutureBuilder, everything is ok. The method return data correctly.
This is the code refactored:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:xxxx/models/task_model.dart';
import 'package:xxxx/shared/loading.dart';

class AddTask extends StatefulWidget {
  static const id = 'add_task';

  @override
  _AddTaskState createState() => _AddTaskState();
}

class _AddTaskState extends State<AddTask> {
  final textController = TextEditingController();

  Future<List<TaskModel>> _getTasks() async {
    List<TaskModel> tasks = await _todoHelper.getAllTask();
    print('Tasks data: ${tasks.length}');
    return tasks;
  }

  TaskModel currentTask;

  //list to test with the FlatButton List all tasks
  List<TaskModel> tasksList = [];

  final TodoHelper _todoHelper = TodoHelper();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(32),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            TextField(
              controller: textController,
            ),
            FlatButton(
              child: Text('Insert'),
              onPressed: () {
                currentTask = TaskModel(name: textController.text);
                _todoHelper.insertTask(currentTask);
              },
              color: Colors.blue,
              textColor: Colors.white,
            ),

            //when clicking on this flatButton, I can populate the taskList
            FlatButton(
              child: Text('Show all Tasks'),
              onPressed: () async {
                List<TaskModel> list = await _getTasks();
                setState(() {
                  tasksList = list;
                  print(
                      'TaskList loaded by "flatButton" has ${tasksList.length} rows');
                });
              },
              color: Colors.red,
              textColor: Colors.white,
            ),

//

            FutureBuilder(
              future: _getTasks(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                  // future complete
                  // if error or data is false return error widget
                  if (snapshot.hasError || !snapshot.hasData) {
                    return Text('ERROR or NO-DATA');
                  }

                  // return data widget
                  return ListItems(context, snapshot.data);

                  // return loading widget while connection state is active
                } else
                  return Loading();
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

//*****************************************
class ListItems extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<TaskModel> snapshot;
  final BuildContext context;

  ListItems(this.context, this.snapshot);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: snapshot == null ? 0 : snapshot.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            TaskModel t = snapshot[index];
            return Text(' ${t.id} - ${t.name}');
          }),
    );
  }
}
```